# Extending Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of values all in a row (500+), like:

```
AAC80013, /ACY03537, /ADC64131, /AED59827, /AKC13125, /APS84849, etc...
```

and would like to know to merge them all into one cell so they are as follows:

```
AAC80013, ACY03537, ADC64131, AED59827, AKC13125, APS84849,
```

I have tried to do a merge and center and this didn't work. I have however found a way to do this by using an `=A4&B4&C4` etc... but I was hoping someone could either advise me of a quicker way to merge them rather than go though and do each one individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question's tags it sounds like you are looking for a simple, non-macro solution.

The process of stitching together multiple text values into one text value is called concatenation. You've discovered one method to do this with formulas using ampersands `&` between the items. Another is the CONCATENATE() function that can be used in a formula. But frankly, both of these are terrible if you want to do a lot of concatenations. The CONCATENATE() function is particularly irksome because while it should accept a range of values to stitch together, it does not!

So if the concatenation work is complex, the most common way to simplify the workload is to write a VBA macro. But that's programming and requires you to know a few things.

Here is a simple alternative. It is a manual workflow that can make this task very quick and painless.

Let's assume your values are in the range `A4:Z4` and also assume that row 5 is empty. Just follow these steps:

1.) In cell `B5` enter this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A5&A4&B4,"/",", ")
```

2.) Now copy `B5` and select the range `C5:Z5` and paste.

3.) By now `Z5` will look fearsome. No worries. Copy `Z5`.

4.) Right-click on the cell you wish to have your final list in and select Paste Special - Values.

5.) Select row 5 and delete all of that.

That's it. It takes about two seconds once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub combine()
Dim lastCol As Integer, xRow As Integer
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim delimiter As String, firstCellInfo As String

firstCellInfo = Cells(1, 1).Value

xRow = 1 'change this to the row with your data.
delimiter = "/"

lastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
Set rng = Range(Cells(xRow, 1), Cells(xRow, lastCol))

For Each cel In rng
    If Left(cel.Value, Len(delimiter)) = delimiter Then
        Debug.Print Right(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value) - Len(delimiter))
        cel.Value = Right(cel.Value, Len(cel) - Len(delimiter))
    End If
    If cel.Column > 1 Then firstCellInfo = firstCellInfo + ", " + cel.Value
Next cel

Cells(2, 1).Value = firstCellInfo

End Sub
```

Note: Change the `xRow` to whatever row has your data.  Also, there's a delimiter `/` in each cell except the first one - so the loop will remove that, if it exists, and add the result to a string `firstCellInfo`.   At the end of the loop, I placed this combined data into `B1` - just so you can run this and make sure this works.  If you want to put the info back in A1, just change `Cells(2,1).Value` to `Cells(1,1).Value`.

Also, if you want to delete the extra data (columns B onward), just add this after the `Cells(2,1).Value = firstCellInfo`:

```
Set rng = Range(Cells(xRow, 2), Cells(xRow, lastCol))
rng.Clear
```